# Coding return general method

Tags: c#

I don't get what the the general method for return is used for? Is it basically a statement to return the values calculated?

Can someone help me out with this question for my exam?

Create a method to calculate and return the volume of a box, given its length, height and breadth.

1. Write the header line of the above method.
2. Write the calculation whereby the calculated volume (where volume= length * breadth * height) is passed back to the calling method.

Comment: if you want to learn you need to have passion into it :3

Comment: Your method will take three parameters as an input and return the calculated value. Now you can fugure out how a method signature looks :)

Comment: Dude, there are like ... 10million tutorials and youtube videos if you google "C# for beginners" and the skills you need to solve this will be taught within the first 20 minutes of each tutorial/video/book ...

Comment: You need to write a method that accepts three parameters of type decimal. Create a decimal variable inside the method and assign the caluclated value to it. Finaly return the  variable (value). Google is your firend! a good start to C#:  https://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/en-us/training-courses/c-fundamentals-for-absolute-beginners-8295

Comment: Filed under _homework_...

Answer (score 1):

For a void method, a `return` statement end the processing of the method before the code of that method end.

For a non-void method, you use `return someThing` also to return the result ("someThing") of the method.

The calculation itself is up to you - we will not make your homework for you.